# jQuery remove class from UL hierarchy except for

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mpire/yTzGA/1/

Using jQuery how can I remove the "active" class from all LIs except for the one furthest (deepest) from the root?

```
<div class="navpole">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                     <ul>
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the desired result:

```
<div class="navpole">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                     <ul>
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                     </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** This assumes that there is only a single path from the root to the deepest `.active` element, which contains *all*  `.active`  Elements under that root (i.e. no branching). If that cannot be guaranteed, then this solution won't work.

```
$('.navpole .active').slice(0, -1).removeClass('active');
```

Since the order of the selected elements is the order in which their appear in the document, the "deepest" element is inevitably the last one, so we have to remove the class from every selected element, but the last one.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/8/)

Comment: Uhhh .... are you sure?  What if the "deepest" one were to be found way way down in an "early" child of the parent `<div>`?  I guess it depends on whether it's a depth-first or breadth-first traversal.

Comment: That's why I said said that this assumes a single path which contains every .active element.

Comment: And this is usually given if you have a nested menu for example. Of course if this cannot be ensured, then this wouldn't work, but if it ensured, keep it simple :)

Answer (score 4):

Sort them by number of parents and exclude the last one as that will be the one nested the furthest regardless of markup, and remove the class on the rest of them

```
$('.active').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).parents().length > $(b).parents().length;
}).not(':last').removeClass('active');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/5/)

To do it for each navpole, just wrap it in a `each()`

```
$('.navpole').each(function() {
    $('.active', this).sort(function(a,b) {
        return $(a).parents().length > $(b).parents().length;
    }).not(':last').removeClass('active');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/6/)

Comment: I think this is the only reliable way to do it. I started typing in something to get the elements and then do a `.reduce()` to find the one with the biggest parent chain, but it got messy.

Comment: This is a great solution! However, in the instance that there are two or more active items on the lowest level, their active state is preserved for only one of them. This may or may not be what the poster intends.

Comment: This solution would work for my use case because the business rules dictate that there can only ever be one active list item per level of the hierarchy.

Comment: @CharlesWesley: In that case there is not even a need for sorting the elements. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling - I guess the question is, what if you have something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/10/), it no longer gets the deepest nested element, just the last element ?

Comment: @adeneo: Of course. But if the rule is *"there can only ever be one active list item per level of the hierarchy"* (which is a much better description of the constraint than what I wrote in my answer), then this case never occurs. Of course solutions should as general as possible (IMO) but simplicity is important as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `each()` to loop through the `.active` elements and remove the class if its sibling elements have a `ul` child:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fBR2X/)

```
$('.navpole .active').each(function(){
    if($(this).siblings().children('ul').length > 0 ){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. The only problem I could see is if it's possible to have an active item WITH inactive list items below.  In that case, this would inactivate that item. If it's not possible, then this looks like the most succinct answer. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fBR2X/4/

Comment: @Joel Good point. 1+ to your answer. Now that you updated it, it seems to work in all situations. Mine also doesn't work with any given markup, it assumes the siblings will have `ul` children elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep just the last `.active` item into each `.navpole` you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //For each navpole
    $('.navpole').each(function(){
    //Find number of active elements
        var len = $('.active',this).length;
    //Filter that elements and remove class for all elements except the last one
        $('.active',this).filter(function(index){
        return index != len-1;
        }).removeClass('active');
    }) 
});
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/4/)**

Comment: The doesn't really work! It just removes the class on the elements that does not have an index that is the same as the lenght, or the number of elements, so really you could just do `$('.active').not(':last').removeClass('active')`, and it would be the same as your code, it has nothing to do with the nesting depth, it removes the class on all elements but the last !

Comment: And here's proof -> http://jsfiddle.net/yTzGA/7/, when adding an element that is not nested as deep later in the DOM, that element remains, as it's the last one ?

Comment: @adeneo you are right I'm learning in the way I make answers here good to know your concept learn something new. +1 for you seems your solution works

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. The previous example by adeneo is great, but has issues if you have two active nodes at the same level at the lowest level of the hierarchy and want all of their active states preserved. This version will keep all lowest nodes selected if they're at the same level in the hierarchy.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.navpole').each(function () {
        var active = $(this).find(".active").map(function () {
            return $(this).parents().length;
        });
        var maxParents = Math.max.apply(Math, active);
        $(this).find(".active").each(function () {
            if ($(this).parents().length != maxParents) $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
    });
});
```

here is a fiddle to illustrate:
http://jsfiddle.net/CGcr9/1/